# Can I use 'quite the collection of people' to mean 'birds of a feather'?

Tags: phrases, idiomatic-language

Can I use 'quite the collection of people' to mean 'birds of a feather'? For example, is the following use of 'quite the collection of people' natural?

Aria asked who are Bob's teammates in a tournament for nobles, Alice told Aria their names and informed her of their infamous family backgrounds, then she went on to comment,

> Quite the collection of people.

Notes on Alice's words: What people in that team have in common is they all are from infamous families, that is, her comment is about their infamy.

Comment: "quite the birds of a feather" is an unorthodox use of the saying.

Comment: @JamesK Then what should I say?

Comment: "Quite the... " is a somewhat informal mainly US usage.

Comment: Well, if the are "teammates", then maybe you should say "team".

Comment: The *definite* article in *Quite **the** collection of people* would imply a relatively unlikely context and intended meaning (that this particular collection is an excellent  example of the kind of diverse group that everyone knows is "a good thing"). That's as opposed to the *indefinite* article, where  *Quite **a** collection of people* simply expresses the speaker's surprise at the composition of the group (with no special implication as to whether it's diverse or not, or a good or a bad thing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An odd context!

I could imagine, in fairly casual contexts someone saying "That's quite **a** collection of people!".  The meaning would be very context-dependent, and probably vague/ambiguous.  It means that the collection seems special in some way — perhaps there is an interesting variety of people, or the people are all special in some way, or perhaps it is just that the collection is surprisingly large.

If the "collection of people" are a "team" or a "squad" then it would be better to say "quite a team".

I would not use "quite the birds of a feather" at all.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the previous replies, those two expressions don't really mean the same thing. It's hard to imagine a setting where they would be interchangeable.

"Quite a collection" (**a**, not **the**) refers to a collection that is special in some way. Suppose someone showed you their collection of coins or dolls or Lego creations. If you reply "That's quite a collection", you would be saying how impressed you were by the size or contents of the collection.

"Birds of a feather" doesn't refer to what is special about a group, but what is **common** to the group. It's often used in the extended proverb "Birds of a feather flock together." For example, you might use it to describe all the people attending a Star Trek convention. They all have the same interest; in that respect they are all "birds of a feather."